# Laravel API server architecture problems

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent, architecture

I am creating an API server with Laravel and I have some questions about the architecture. I am working on rewriting an existing system and we have a multi-tenant service. For each customer, we have one main database one that changes yearly. We get information on which database to use from the requests(db and db_year). Now I am struggling with ORM structure.
How should I create databases and migrate them for each customer? How do I set the database for each request so that the relevant data could be sent?

I managed to do it without creating the databases and just getting it from existing databases but this is not the structure I wanted to build the system.

Comment: Did you try to use some package like [Laravel-multitenancy](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v3/installation/using-multiple-databases)? I think it will give a clear understanding of how to setup a multi tenant api.